# Why the instance attributes in python are defined three times like this?

Tags: python

why is the instance attribute defined three times in python: once in the parenthesis, once in with the self keyword and once in the assignment

```
class Details():
   def __init__(self,name,age):
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
```

Comment: It has to with how python handles instance implementation. `self` is the same as `this` in other languages. You are assigning instance (as opposed to class) level variables with names that can be used in instance methods. `Details('abc',2).do_something()`

Comment: Hi Elliott Frisch I'm a beginner and I really couldn't understand what your telling. Can you be a bit more detailed about what your telling

Comment: `name` in parenthesis and after `=` is the same local variable which you can't access in other functions in class - so it is not so useful. `self.name` is class variable which you can access in other functions in class - so it is very useful.

Comment: Try `help(Details)` -- I think you will find it very informative.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` is a function/method and like any other functions has "local variables" just like :

```
def fn(a, b):
    print(a, b)
```

In your example, `name`, `age` in parameters and in right hand side of the assignments are just like `a` and `b`. You can choose any name you want for these variables.

But the `name` and `age` which are parts of `self.name` and `self.age` statements respectively, are attributes of your new-created instance(which `self` points to it). The name you choose for this attributes will exist in instance's `__dict__`(instance's namespace dictionary), so that's how you can call them later.

```
class Details:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

obj = Details('John', 20)
print(obj.name)
print(obj.age)
```

Answer (score 0):

- `__init__` is the constructor (in OOP terms) to create `Details` object. in Python, a constructor's first parameter is always `self`.
- `self` points to the newly created object. It got two attributes, name and age.
- the parameters, `name` and `age` inside parentheses, can have different names as well. So, the following code works the same :

  ```
   class Details():
       def __init__(self,n,a):
          self.name = n
          self.age = a
  ```